# How can I wrap any impl of std::error::Error to ease error propagation?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to simplify the error flow in a webapp I'm working on, and my plan was to make a struct that implements `std::error::Error` and just forwards the result of `description()` for whatever kind of error it's wrapped around. I've implemented `From` for the types of errors I want to wrap, so this struct makes it easy to use `try!` to get a uniform error result.  Here's what I have so far for the struct:

```rust
#![feature(convert)]
use std::error::{Error};
use std::fmt::{self,Display,Formatter};
use std::io::{self,Read};
use std::ops::Deref;
use std::fs::{File};

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct StrErr{
    desc:String,
    c: Option<Box<Error>>
}
impl StrErr{
    pub fn new(msg:String) ->Self{
        StrErr{desc:msg, c:None}
    }
}

impl Error for StrErr{
    fn description(&self) -> &str{
        self.desc.as_str()
    }
    fn cause(& self) -> Option<& Error> {
        self.c.map(|e| e.deref())
    }
}

impl Display for StrErr {
    fn fmt(&self, f:&mut Formatter) -> Result<(),fmt::Error> {
        f.write_str(self.desc.as_str())
    } 
}

impl From<io::Error> for StrErr {
    fn from(o:io::Error) -> Self {
        StrErr{desc: String::from(o.description()),c:Some(Box::new(o))}
    }
}


fn main(){
    let contrived = Some("foo.txt")
        .ok_or_else(|| StrErr::new(String::from("error message")))
        .and_then(|filename| Ok(try!(File::open(filename))))
        .and_then(|mut file| {
            let mut content = String::new();
            try!(file.read_to_string(&mut content));
            Ok(content)
        });
    if let Ok(content) = contrived {
        println!("Got content: {}", content);
    } else {
        println!("got an error");
    }
}
```

[playground](http://is.gd/Gvzten)

The problem is with the `cause()` method - I can't return a reference to the inner `Error` instance because `e` doesn't live long enough. Is there a different way I can structure this so that I can keep the generic reference to anything that implements `Error` (which I currently do by putting it in a Box) but I can still fully implement the `Error` trait (which is expecting a ref to the parent `Error`)?

I've worked around it by just punting on `cause()` and having it return `None`, but I'd much rather conform to the intent of the trait.

```
rustc 1.2.0-nightly (613e57b44 2015-06-01) (built 2015-06-02)
```

Comment: Sorry about that. Your answer worked perfectly, but I went ahead and added the complete broken example anyway for future reference.

Comment: Thanks! It's impressive the number of people that get their answer and forget about making the question any good. Go you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one way you can convert an `Option<Box<Trait>>` to an `Option<&Trait>`. I'm avoiding all of the trait implementation to clearly show the interesting code:

```
use std::error::Error;

pub struct StrErr {
    c: Option<Box<Error>>
}

impl StrErr {
    fn cause(&self) -> Option<&Error> {
        self.c.as_ref().map(|e| &**e)
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

We use [`Option::as_ref`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/core/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_ref) to avoid consuming the `self.c` item. The `map` closure is provided with a `&Box<Trait>`, so we dereference it twice to get to a `Trait`, and then reference it once to get to a `&Trait`.